# Create two level map out of a json map using lodash

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a json list and I'm trying to regroup the objects in this map with two keys. For the time being I only succeded grouping by a one key using lodash groupBy, but I'm unable to find a correct way to create the **row** key and group the size/qty in this new array. I can use ES6 or lodash in my code

```
const colorsMap= _.groupBy(colors, 'Id');
```

my initial json looks like this:

```
colors =  [
{
    "Id": "1",
    "color": "red",
    "size": "10"
    "QTY": "2000"
    "ref": "tr"
},
{
    "Id": "1",
    "color": "red",
    "size": "25"
    "QTY": "3000"
    "ref": "tr"
},
{
    "Id": "1",
    "color": "blue",
    "size": "15"
    "QTY": "2050"
    "ref": "gt",
},
{
    "Id": "2",
    "color": "red",
    "size": "18"
    "QTY": "2010"
    "ref": "tt"
},
]
```

and I'm trying to have something like this

```
 [
 "1": [
   {
     "Id": "1",
     "color": "red",
     "row": [
          {
            "size": "10"
            "QTY": "2000"
          },
          {
            "size": "25"
            "QTY": "3000"
          },
          {
            "size": "15"
            "QTY": "0"
          }
      ],
     "ref": "tr"
    },
    {
    "Id": "1",
    "color": "blue",
     "row": [
          {
            "size": "10"
            "QTY": "0"
          },
          {
            "size": "25"
            "QTY": "0"
          },
          {
            "size": "15"
            "QTY": "2050"
          }
      ],
    "ref": "gt",
  }
 ],
 "2": [
   {
     "Id": "2",
     "color": "red",
     "row": [
          {
            "size": "18"
            "QTY": "2010"
          }
      ],
     "ref": "tt"
   }
  ]
]
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `colorsMap= _.groupBy(colors, 'Id')` then on colorsMap I do a forEach but unable to create the row attribute on distinct keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping the colors by id, then group by again by color, and map the values of the 2nd grouping to the objects you need:

```js
const colors =  [{"Id":"1","color":"red","size":"10","QTY":"2000","ref":"tr"},{"Id":"1","color":"red","size":"25","QTY":"3000","ref":"tr"},{"Id":"1","color":"blue","size":"15","QTY":"2050","ref":"gt"},{"Id":"2","color":"red","size":"18","QTY":"2010","ref":"tt"}];

const result = _(colors)
  .groupBy('Id') // group by id
  .mapValues((values) => _(values) // map the values
    .groupBy('color') // group by color
    .mapValues((v) => ({ // map the resulting arrays
      /* get the id and color from the 1st item in the array */
      id: v[0].Id,
      color: v[0].color,
      rows: v.map(({ size, QTY }) => ({ // map all elements to row objects
        size,
        QTY
      }))
    }))
     .value())
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this recuperates only the first color, it does not result of an array of colors

Comment: works great tkx, I just had to add .value() to the second groupBy

Comment: Welcome. I've added the 2nd `.value()` to the example as well.